# How can i Delimite and Group Json value on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, delimiter

I need to delimite and categorize below json value

for ex : `"sub3[+]888800"` `sub3` is category code and `888800` is element of category.

```
["sub3[+]888800","sub3[+]100000","06[+]888800","06[+]100000"]
```

i need to result like that

```
sub3 -> 888800, 100000

06 - > 888800, 100000






 List<string> seledItems = this.ResetSeledItems();
            this.litDebug.Text = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(seledItems);
        var json = this.litDebug.Text;
        var strs = JArray.Parse(json);

    // process the delimiter
    var items =
        from str in strs.Select(x => (string)x)
        let idx = str.IndexOf("[+]")
        select new
        {
            tag = str.Substring(0, idx),
            data = str.Substring(idx + 3)
        };
    // do the grouping
    var grps =
        from item in items
        group item by item.tag into grp
        select new
        {
            tag = grp.Key,
            items = grp.Select(x => x.data)
        };
    foreach (var grp in grps)
    {
        string tag = grp.tag.ToString();

        for(int i=0;i<=3 ; i++)
        {
            string item = grp.items.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
// prepare the data
var json = "['sub3[+]888800','sub3[+]100000','06[+]888800','06[+]100000']";
var strs = JArray.Parse(json);
// process the delimiter
var items =
    from str in strs.Select(x => (string)x)
    let idx = str.IndexOf("[+]")
    select new
    {
      tag = str.Substring(0, idx),
      data = str.Substring(idx + 3)
    };
// do the grouping
var grps =
    from item in items
    group item by item.tag into grp
    select new
    {
      tag = grp.Key,
      items = grp.Select(x => x.data)
    };
// output
foreach (var grp in grps)
  Console.WriteLine(grp.tag + " -> " + String.Join(", ", grp.items));
```

with these `using` clauses:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: thanks for reply; im getting error  in this line 
from str in strs.Select(x => (string)x)
char cannot convert to string

Comment: Isn't your JSON an array of strings? What's the JSON you're actually using?

Comment: List<string> seledItems = this.ResetSeledItems();
        var strs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(seledItems);

Comment: Then your `strs` will be a string, not a JSON array of strings. Please make your `strs` my `json`, and try again.

Comment: tag is getting as well , but items no way getting 
items = ->> "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.String,System.String],System.String]"

Comment: Perhaps you should show me your code. Please edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: Well, your last foreach loop does nothing in effect. What kind of output do you want? Do you want the groups to be stored in some kind of data structure? Or do you want them to be shown somewhere in certain format?